# runway-restricted airports?

Tags: airbus-a330, airbus-neo

A video about the improvements on the A330 Neo says that its new flaps settings make it better at runway-restricted airports.  What does that mean?

Answer (score 5):

The "runway restriction" mentioned in the video means that the runway length may be too short for some aeroplanes altogether or it may restrict the maximum takeoff weight for certain aircraft, since the heavier the aircraft is, the more lift it requires to take off.

As described in the video, one major factor in takeoff performance is the flap setting. Flaps increase the lift provided by the wing, enabling takeoff at shorter distance. The downside of higher flap settings is increased drag.

Due to the nature of lift and drag equations, there is an optimum flap angle for any given weight and runway length combination. Unfortunately the flap settings in aircraft are discrete: there is a limited number of settings to select from, meaning there may be conditions in which the lower setting is too low (producing too little lift), and the next one is too high (producing too much drag).

The A330 Neo mitigates this problem by providing additional flap settings to "fill the gaps", enabling better optimized takeoff performance. I made a screen capture of the video showing the additional settings place in between the original ones, with green and red dots I added. The graph is interpreted such that the area below the bold black line is usable, the area above the line is impossible to achieve: if the weight and runway combination plots over the black line, the aeroplane will overrun the runway on takeoff.

[image: Chart of maximum takeoff weight vs runway length based on flap settings]

From this graph you can see that the areas marked with the red dots were not achievable before with runway lengths marked with respective green dots on the horizontal axis. Either the plane was too heavy, or the runway was too short. With new intermediate flap settings extra lift is available without critically more drag.